# how to extract images from Google places API android

Tags: android

```
        PlacePhotoMetadataResult result3 = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlacePhotos(mGoogleApiClient3,place.getId()).await();
        if (result3.getStatus().isSuccess() && result3!= null){
            PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer placePhotoMetadataBuffer = result3.getPhotoMetadata();
            PlacePhotoMetadata photo = placePhotoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
            Bitmap image = photo.getPhoto(mGoogleApiClient3).await().getBitmap();
            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
```

how to build google API client in this code or is there any other method to access image by google Place API?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from following URl.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference="enter photo refernce key here"&maxheight=100&maxwidth=100&key="enter google key here"